# C++ Equivalent of C# Arraylist to hold Multiple Data Types

Tags: c++, types, containers

Looking for an equivalent container class that matches to C#'s Arraylist collections class. Is there anything that comes close to a container that can provide index based enumeration as well as hold multiple data types.

What I am trying to do is implement a Model-View-Controler. I am trying to create a Controller that can internally manage different types of shape data-types (e.g.: Box2D, Circle2D, Circle3D, etc)

```
//Controller code
class Controller
{
    //internally track all shapes...

    void CreateShape(const Box2d &box); 
    void CreateShape(const Box3d &box);
    void CreateShape(const Circle2d &circle);

    //More Add/Edit/Remove Shape methods...

    void Reset(); //clear the container of shapes...
};
```

I am trying to create an vector or a different type of container that can hold multiple data types. For example:

```
//Is this line of code possible??
vector <int, string> vec;    

int i=0;
string str = "test";

//add different data-type objs into my vector mutable array
vec.push_back(i);
vec.push_back(str);
```

Please advise, if there are other container classes in C++ that might help me achieve this functionality or there is a way to use vector class to store multiple data-types.

Comment: ¤ The question sounds like a red herring: DESIGN ERROR. But given that you really want that, the simplest is just a struct type that contains an int *and* a string. And perhaps a member that says which. The Pascal-like solution is a "variant record", which means a union with a member denoting which union member is currently valid. That works in C++11 but not for types with constructors in C++03. You could use a boost::variant or the other such Boost class, I forget the name. But, given that this is most probably a design error, I advice keep it simple, be prepared to remove it. Cheers & hth.,

Comment: @Serge: please also explain to the OP one way to access those elements. Cheers,

Comment: Following up to Alf's comment. If Visual Studio is used your "variant record" is literally VARIANT :-)

Comment: @Alf P. Steinbach: Thank you for your feedback. I  was also thinking of looking at the Boost library. I was working with a few other groups and was trying to avoid using minimize use of external libraries, then STD.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want something like this:

```
class Shape {
public:
    virtual void rotate(double degrees) = 0;
    virtual void scale(double newScale) = 0;
    virtual ~Shape(){}
    //etc, etc, etc...
};

class Box2d : public Shape {
public:
    virtual void rotate(double degrees) {
        //Code for rotating...
    }

    //Implement other virtual methods...
};
class Circle2d : public Shape {}; //Implement virtual methods
class Box3d : public Shape {}; //Implement virtual methods


int main() {
    vector<Shape*> items;
    items.push_back(new Box2d());
    items.push_back(new Circle2d());

    //Now doing this:
    items[i]->rotate(180.0);
    //Will call Box2d's rotate function
}
```

Comment: I am trying to create an interface to internally manage different shape data-types, Model-View-Controller design pattern. I am working on the Controller, that would store different types of shapes internally but provide overloaded add/remove/edit methods to the client. E.g client code: `Controller cc; cc.CreateShape(new Box3D()); cc.CreateShape(new Circle3D());` etc...'

Comment: If you have some sort of heirarchy already, then what I have is usually a pretty good solution. Keep around a vector of Shape pointers who's virtual methods can call the concrete implementations in your deriving classes.

Comment: The hierarchy is good and I would have gone that route but I have 2d and 3d shapes, so I am stuck with a Shape2D and Shape3D parent classes. Still need somehow manage two data-types internally. My last option would be to create 2 vectors `vector<Shape2D> vec1;` and `vector<Shape3D> vec1;`

Comment: @badboy11: if they don't share a common interface, they should not be in the same vector.  Use two different vectors.

Comment: So extend the hierarchy... make both Shape2D and Shape3D inherit from Shape. If you need to distinguish between a 2D or 3D shape at runtime, you can use dynamic_cast<Shape2D*>(Shape* ptr): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_cast. Preferably, they should have the same interface (or at least a common subset)

Comment: I wanted to keep behaviour separate from data so I have a IBase2D that has all behaviours that all 2d shapes should perform. It is inherited by Shape2D class. All concrete 2D shapes inherit from Shape2D. The same applies for 3D as well.  E.g:  `//IBase.h`  `//all 2D shape beviours...`  `//Shape2D.h`  `class Shape2D : virtual public IBase`  `{`  `//data members for 2D shapes and getter/setter here`  `};`

Comment: If you can't merge the IBase2D and IBase3D, then you should have two different containers, one to IBase2D pointers and one to IBase3D pointers.

Comment: Thanks all. I had a pretty strong feeling that I would mostly likely have to create two separate storage containers internally   `vector<Shape2D> vec1;` and `vector<Shape3D> vec2;`   and manage them somehow internally.

Comment: (+1) "createShape(...)" methods suggest implicit or natural inheritance ...+

Comment: createShape(....); is just overloaded methods in my Controller class, no inheritance.

Comment: @badboy11: He means that since you're using the same name for that function there is some implied relationship between the different types.

Answer (score 0):

The only way your going to put more than one data type into a vector is to encapsulate it.